# Salvaging a combinatorics problem by dividing by $\frac{26}{7}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There is a lotto consisting of $44$ balls; those numbered $1,5,9...$ are red, $2,6,10...$ are blue, $3,7,11...$ are yellow and $4,8,12...$ are green. What is the probability that the selected six balls contain $4$ colors?

Well I know that there are $11$ of each color, and my initial logic was $\binom{11}{1}^4\binom{40}{2}$ since you can double up any of the balls to fill up to six balls total. Then I realised this double counts horribly. I notice that this can be salvaged by dividing by $26/7$. This sounds really naive but could this really be a solution? I would want to know what $26/7$ represents.

I know there is a correct way to consider cases however, and used it to solve the problem successfully.

But is it possible to get rid of double counting using my initial thoughts?

Comment: I assume you are choosing without replacement? In any case, Inclusion-Exclusion was designed for problems like this.

Comment: As an alternative, given that the numbers are so very small, you could write out the possible good patterns, e.g. ( $3$ of one color, $1$ each of the others)  or ($2$ each of two colors, $1$ each of the others) and count those cases separately.  This isn't usually a good idea (because the number of patterns can be high and enumerating them can be a challenge) but it is perfectly feasible here.

Comment: The $26/7$ looks like a nice coincidence.  It seems as if you had $24$ balls the factor might be $228/61$,  with  $28$ balls then $138/37$, with  $32$ balls then $108/29$, with  $36$ balls then $93/25$, and with $40$ balls then $420/113$, and more complicated for many other cases

Comment: @Henry yes I thought so! For some reason this time it felt possibly "meaningful" this time. Does it represent anything derivable?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach cannot be salvaged as is unless you work through case by case of overcounting and subtract them.

For choosing $6$ balls without replacement, as you mention you already solved it working through cases which are,

$ \displaystyle {4 \choose 2} {11 \choose 2}^2 {11 \choose 1}^2 + {4 \choose 1} {11 \choose 3} {11 \choose 1}^3$

But if the numbers are big, working case by case may get tedious. So a general approach will be to apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion. Then, number of favorable selections can be written as,

$ \displaystyle {44 \choose 6} - {4 \choose 1} { 33 \choose 6} + {4 \choose 2} {22 \choose 6} - {4 \choose 3} {11 \choose 6}$

Comment: This PIE approach seems very promising

Comment: @user71207 it is indeed the case, esp. when working through cases becomes tedious. Also when we work through many cases, the chances of missing out certain scenarios is likely too.